# How can I get a second review of my grades?

Tags: etiquette, grading, harassment

How can I ask for a different faculty member to evaluate my final grade as opposed to my professor?

I know this is an "odd" question but if there is a possible way for that to happen I would greatly appreciate advice.

I will leave the details out of it, but the long & short of it is that this professor has gone out of his way to publicly humiliate me on false claims which I will be contesting. But my concern isn't proving correctness, but rather ensuring that my grade is fair.

Comment: This depends entirely on the regulations of your own university.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can petition the head of the department/program if you think that your professor has a conflict of interest and can apparently not be fair in grading your class. But you have to be prepared for the department head to then ask the professor what his opinion on the issue is -- and in all likelihood, the professor will say that nothing untoward is going on and that he/she can be unbiased and fair.

In other words, if you're asking for the judge to be removed from the trial, you better have evidence. For example, you probably want to make sure that other students can corroborate your claims.

I'm saying this because as professors, we see students claim all the time that they are treated unfairly -- but in the vast majority of the cases, they're just not very good students. So expect that just making such a claim will, alone, not get you very far. You'll have to have evidence.

Comment: In my academic life, I have seen many people abusing this option, more so in Europe. What is considered as a solid evidence against conflict of interest?

Comment: @givnv does "this option" refer to grading by a different faculty member or to using the argument that many students who ask for that are just not very good students?

Comment: A related phenomenon are students who are used at being the best of the class, and have to get used to being "just" one of many good students when they move to ever more selective courses. Some experience real problems adjusting to that new situation, which can manifest itself in many different ways. One of which is blaming the person teaching that course.

Comment: I would advise the student to tape, or otherwise record the professor publicly humiliating him or her. If these charges "stick," it almost becomes irrelevant whether or not the grade is fair.

Comment: If you could record what you saw as a humiliation, it could be an evidence. Please note this is not legal everywhere though. But even if it is illegal (as of not usable in court), I wonder if you couldn't still use it in front of your headmaster, depending of how much it is illegal of course.

Comment: @DanChaltiel: I was assuming that it is "legal" (under university regulations) to tape lectures. If so, this could be part of the lecture. And even if inadmissible in court, it might help in a university proceeding. Of course, if the university does not allow taping of lectures, this advice is "off."